# Unwanted print error of rejected promise for state transition of ui-router to console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using the [resolve](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/state.statedeclaration.html#resolve) property of ui-routers state definition for angular 1 to provide a function which returns a promise. The provided function should check if the user is allowed to visit the state or not.

If the returned promise gets rejected, the state transition does not happen - just what I want to achieve. Additionally I can listen for the `$stateChangeError` event to get details about the rejection. All works fine.

My problem is that the error is printed to the console what I want to avoid.

Consider this state definiton:

```
$stateProvider.state({
    name: 'about',
    url: '/about',
    template: '<h3>Its the UI-Router hello world app!</h3>',
    resolve: {
      isAllowed:function(){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
          reject(new Error("not allowed"));
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

which results in the following error printed to the console, whenever this state is visited:

[image: console error]

Please see this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dqKWCwswXd1ttMEmksKU) for a minimal working example.

Is there any way to get rid of the console error while maintaining the rest of the behavior?

Comment: btw u can use `Promise.reject()` instead of new Promise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the version of `ui-router` you used `angular-ui-router@1.0.0`, is in the BETA version, there are few `console.log` lines are left in their scripts.

So, you can use the more stable version to overcome this issue, for example you can use  `angular-ui-router@0.3.1`

**This gets rid of the `console error` while maintaining the rest of the behavior**

[Here is a new plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lp8DElQosBaHj7i4U0n3?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

It could be because of version of **angular-ui-router** you are using. Try [**This version (0.4.2)**](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.js). You wont get error in this version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use alternate way like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (evt, toState,
toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
    if(not_allowed) {
       evt.preventDefault();
    }
}
```